# Keys with duplicate letters and their alphabetic order

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String which is my key and I have a way of assigning each letter in that key a number that represents its order in the alphabet. For example, if my key is the word "Security", the output is `4, 1, 0, 6, 3, 2, 5, 7`, and my code is as follows:

```
String key = "Security".toLowerCase();
String alphabet = Arrays.stream(key.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
int[] order = new int[key.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    order[i] = alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i));
}
```

I've omitted printing out the array here...

This code works fine if the key doesn't contain any duplicate letters. However if the key becomes "aardvark" for example, then the output becomes `0, 0, 5, 3, 7, 0, 5, 4` which is problematic. I don't know how to get around this issue. The desired output should be `0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4`.

Any suggestions? I'm new to Java programming so may not understand very complex solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I thought I had @JoeC. I guess the only thing I didn't include was my attempt at solving this issue. I duplicated `order`, and then using a `for` loop I checked to see if there were any duplicates, and if there were, increased the original array by one. But that didn't work because I still didn't get unique counts for all letters.

Comment: Could you please explain why the expected output is `0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 5, 4`. In my understanding the first `a` in `aardvark` maps to `0`. So does the second. Please explain why the second mapping should be 'incremented'.

Comment: @Granada, we need how you generate the key.

Comment: @blafasel, that's not the expected output, it's the desired output which I don't know how to obtain.

Comment: @oldercoder I just input the key manually.

Comment: read the question again @blafasel ist understandable. just think again. hes generating an alphabet and wants the word to be coded in this alphabet (coding theroy).

Comment: @blafasel, it looks like the ordering is done first based on the alphanumeric value and second by the position in the "key" word, so that the output contains only unique index numbers.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks for your help. I still can't read requirement this out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be do "zero" out the letters as they are used:

```
String key = "aardvark".toLowerCase();
String alphabet = Arrays.stream(key.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println("alphabet: " + alphabet);
int[] order = new int[key.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
  order[i] = alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i));
  alphabet = alphabet.replaceFirst( ""+key.charAt(i), "0" ); //Zero out chars as they are used
  System.out.println(order[i]);
}
```

Comment: fails if his string contains a zero.

Comment: True, but this is just an example.  You can use any character you like that you know won't be in the string. You could use a space (" "), any special character (!@#$%^&*(){}:" (etc) or probably control characters too.

Comment: Ok. But your code has the need that a character out of the charset cannot be used. That's the case anyway. That's something I wanted to point out. No downvote. Just a hint.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem because there are characters I won't be using (such as zeros). It's simple and effective. I didn't know about the `replaceFirst` function.

Comment: @Granada To check out what fuctions are available its good to check out the Java API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Here is the API for String: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with a trick. You have to do a multisort. To achive this in Java save each entry of both arrays inside one entry of a map. now you can sort this map by key and the values are also sorted. That's the trick.

```
String key = "Security".toLowerCase();
ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
String[] alphabet = key.split(""));
SortedMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    map.put(alphabet[i], i);
}
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<>();
int i = 0;
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    map2.put(entry.getValue(), i++);
}
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
    order.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

something like this should work **untested**

The map is filled with every single char from the key and the value is the position in the original key-string. Because it's a sorted map, the map is sorted by key. So ist ascending by the ord-no. from the chars. The positions are also sorted in the same moment. Now create a second map and fill it with the sorted positions and the index of this positions at the moment. Because it's a sorted map (again) the positions are ordered and the index (values of the map entries) are the keys in the alphabet. This positions and can be read out with an loop and saved inside the order array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an object-oriented solution:

Model the "alphabet" in its own class that's comparable primarily by the alphanumeric value of the character it represents and secondarily by the position it has in the "key" string. The identity of an alphabet (implemented in `equals()`) is determined by its position in the "key" string.

```
public class Alphabet implements Comparable<Alphabet> {

    private final char character;
    private final int position;       

    public Alphabet(char character, int position) {
        this.character = character;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Alphabet) {
            return other != null && position == ((Alphabet) other).position;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alphabet other) {

        int comparison = Character.compare(character, other.character);

        if (comparison != 0) {
            return comparison;
        } else {
           return Integer.compare(position, other.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the conversion algorithm becomes straightforward to implement:

1. Create a `List<Alphabet>` from the input/key string
2. Create a copy of the list and sort it based on the ordering specified in `Alphabet`
3. Create the "ordering array" by iterating over the original alphabet list and for each element, looking up the index that alphabet has in the sorted list

As follows:

```
public static int[] ordering(String input) {

    List<Alphabet> alphabet = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        alphabet.add(new Alphabet(input.charAt(i), i));
    }

    List<Alphabet> sorted = new ArrayList<>(alphabet);
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    int[] ordering = new int[input.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        ordering[i] = sorted.indexOf(alphabet.get(i));
    }
    return ordering;
}
```

A test run with

```
String input1 = "security", input2 = "aardvark";

System.out.println(input1 + ": " + Arrays.toString(ordering(input1)));
System.out.println(input2 + ": " + Arrays.toString(ordering(input2)));
```

produces

```
security: [4, 1, 0, 6, 3, 2, 5, 7]
aardvark: [0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4]
```